# What does {0} mean in String.Format?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

E.g. in the following example:

```
string commandText = string.Format("Select * from {0}", filename);
```

How does the above work?

Comment: Google "String.Format"?

Comment: By providing a SQL Injection attack vector.

Comment: it's called [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) (It's from the MSDN, a handy site for this sort of questions!)

Comment: And where is the ASP.NET here? People should learn something about the .NET Framework first.

Comment: @ErickPetru: Removed the ASP.NET-Tag and Title.

Comment: @Andrew You're jumping to conclusions. if the previous line is something like `string filename = "Users";`, then there is no vulnerability.

Comment: @Jeff Yes, yes I am.  But, the odds of this not being a present or future vulnerability, or of being useful, are quite small.  I realize this could just be an example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`{0}` is a placeholder for the first object given; in this case that's `filename`, so it will insert whatever filename evaluates to in place of `{0}`. Similarly, of course you could use `{1}` and that would be replaced with the second parameter passed, etc.

Answer (score 6):

`{0}` refers to the second parameter passed into `String.Format`. `{1}` refers to the third, `{2}` to the fourth, etc. For example:

```
String.Format("The {0} brown {1} jumps {2} the {3} dog.", "quick", "fox", "over", "lazy")
```

Evaluates to

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
```

Answer (score 2):

It means the value of filename.
[Please see MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It is an indexer to the arguments presented after the `“Select * from {0}”` and can be combined with format specifiers as well. See the documentation for [String.Format Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx). However, you should **NEVER EVER create a SQL command this way** as it is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx) attacks. You should always parameterize SQL queries. See the [How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

The `{0}` is a reference to the first argument passed after the format string.

In your case, `"Select * from {0}"` is the format string and `filename` is the first argument.

As an example:

`String.Format("Select * from {0}{1}{0}","this","database")`

would return:

`"Select * from thisdatabasethis"`