# What is the meaning of "{0}" in strings?

Tags: c#, string, console.writeline

When I used `{0}` in following code:

```
class Program
{
    double width;
    double height;

    public void getData() {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Width:");
        width = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Height:");
        height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public double calcArea() {
        return width * height;
    }

    public void display() {
        Console.WriteLine("Area is : {0}",calcArea());
    }
}

class Area
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.getData();
        p.display();
    }
}
```

The output was:

> Enter Width:
> 6
> Enter Height:
> 9
> Area is : 54

And when I used {0} in this:

```
class NewArea
{
    static void Main(String[] args) {
        double width;
        double height;
        double area;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Width: ");
        width = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Height: ");
        height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        area = width * height;

        Console.WriteLine("Area is: {0}" +area);
    }
}
```

The output was

> Enter Width:
> 4
> Enter Height:
> 5
> Area is: {0}20

What does `{0}` mean?

Comment: Read the [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does {0} mean in String.Format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625750/what-does-0-mean-in-string-format)

Answer (score 6):

There are two different meaning for {0} as you have used.

> Console.WriteLine("Area is : {0}",calcArea());

In above sentence once you give {0} it means that you may provide some value after comma in same sentence as you provide the value 54 after comma so Console figured that and place that value at 0.

In similar way you can provide many values like

> Console.WriteLine("Area for Width {0} and Height {1} is {2}",
>   width, height, calcArea());

OutPut: Area for Width 4 and Height 5 is 20

In another line you used it like

> Console.WriteLine("Area is: {0}" +area);

As in this statement format did not find any comma after {0}" instead found + area so it replace varibale area with value and printed {0} as there is not any matching value {0} which should be given after comma like earlier statement.

Comment: @JayaniPalansooriya Thanks. If you think I have answered it then accept it as answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's a placeholder for the matching parameter in `String.Format` and `WriteLine`

For example:

```
String.Format("My name is {0} and I love {1}!", "Orel Eraki", "Snooker");
```

Output:

> My name is Orel Eraki and I love Snooker!

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Format(String,Object[])
```

The `String` argument obviously takes your string, then you can insert multiple `object` values although this is not necessary. The {0} is just a way to signify that the value of the first object argument will be placed there, similarly {1} means the second and {2} the third. It uses array index syntax.

if you write:

```
String.Format("Value = {0}",val);
```

and `val` is an integer with the value of 20 then the output will be:

'Value=20'

but if you write

```
String.Format("Value = {0}"+val)
```

then you are not giving two arguments to the method but only one, a concatenated string that consists of the "Value= {0}" string and the return value of the `ToString()` method of `val`.

Since there is no second argument the {0} is treated as just a part of the string and not as something with special meaning. That's why the output is: Value = {0}20

Answer (score 0):

It injects the returning value of calcArea() into the string before printing it on the console window

Answer (score 0):

If you use more than one parameter, you need to use `{1}`, `{2}`, etc. You might also use one parameter in more than one place by specifying e.g. `{0}` more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Just see the example below,

```
static void Main()
{
  int a=10;
  int b=20;

  Console.WriteLine(" The value of A is {0} " ,a);

  Console.WriteLine(" The value of A is {0}, the Value of B is {1}",a,b);
  Console.Read();
}
```

see the first WriteLine statement, i'm printing A alone. **{0}** is the place my printing variable will be seen in output. The same way i have written the second statement with two outputs **{0}**, **{1}** So it will be printed accordingly.